# How to (step by step) add a git patch

Tags: git, github

My problem with youtube-dl seems to be a well documented allbeit recent bug: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31542 In the thread a contributor writes "use this patch if u [sic] cannot wait for release fix": https://github.com/ytdl-patched/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2023.02.17.334

I have tried a couple different ways to apply this patch with no success:

```
git diff > https://github.com/ytdl-patched/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2023.02.17.334
bash: https://github.com/ytdl-patched/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2023.02.17.334: No such file or directory
```

and

```
curl https://github.com/critrolesync/critrolesync.github.io/commit/b34accf6638e2dae957b14fb14c4895a92eb2324 | git apply
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  170k    0  170k    0     0   137k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  137k
error: unrecognized input
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: `git diff >` this is trying to write a local diff to a url (that won't work). `curl https://github.com/critrolesync/critrolesync.github.io/commit/b34accf6638e2dae957b14fb14c4895a92eb2324  | git apply` is a html page, not a patch (so that also won't work). [this comment](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31542#issuecomment-1434413384) is  saying 'download my modified version'. Step 1 of applying a patch is having the patch to apply - there isn't one in the question here :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commenter probably means for you to download and install the release of `yt-dlp` they linked, rather than whatever's in git for `youtube-dl`.

Generally an unhelpful comment, since the project `yt-dlp` diverged from `youtube-dl` somewhere around 2020-09-22; they're not the same software anymore, and patches from one are going to be really hard to apply to the other. The two projects *do* have related history, but they've been diverging on purpose for a while.